# preposition 'for' in the sentences with structures like 'compared to'

Tags: grammar

Recently, I've watched one film and ***(have?)*** met there one interesting, at least for me, phrase.

> ...that is nothing compared to what I could be, and perhaps should, be asking for.

My question is, what if I wanted to replace 'for' closer to the beginning? How should I do this?

> ...that is nothing compared to that for what I could, and perhaps should, be asking.
>
> ...that is nothing compared to what for I could, and perhaps should, be asking.

As for me, I don't really think the second one has even a bit of sense, yet I'm not sure.

Thank you in advance, and if you don't mind could you explain the ***'(have?)'***, I mean that I'm wondering whether I should write it or not (I think I should not).

Comment: To start learning about the ellipsis of "have", you might look this up: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/118350

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you put move the preposition from the end of the sentence to before the verb, we add *which* to it.

> That is nothing compared to that for which I could, and perhaps should, be asking.